# fix digit image on hanging board without losing responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have class **numberdisplay** which I want to display number inside a handing board.

I have the below code which display nine boxes exactly inside a name board with responsiveness.

> My problem is that the digit of **numberdisplay** didn't get displayed in hanging board and is not responsive and is fixed, when window resizes the size an alignment changes.

I want the `numberdisplayed` to be `fixed` inside the hanging board and should be responsive.

How can this be done and how to achieve this?

```css
.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
}

.numberdisplay {
  margin-left: 73.99%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: #ffff00 2px;
  border: px solid #000066;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/eV5WW9/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.container2 {
  width: 35vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 41.5vh;
  left: 14vw;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="0">1:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="7">8:10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="4">5:35</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="2container">

        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="11">12:50</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="9">10:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="11">12:50</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="3container">

        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="0">1:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="3">4:45</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="2">3:50</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="numberdisplay" id="2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=11" style="width:160px; height:160px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: @rv7 i want the class nuberdisplay having a digit 11 to be displaye correctly inside the hanging board without losing responsivess

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to calculate the `width` and `height` of a part of an image using CSS or JS.

But, I can calculate it by *hit-and-trial* method and it comes out that the *hanging board* was `0.16%` of the background width always.

Changes done in CSS:

```
/* for .numberdisplay */
margin-left: 72.5%;
margin-top: 16%;

/* for body */
background-size: 100vw auto;
```

The Javascript:

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var number11 = document.querySelector('.numberdisplay img');

function changeSize() {
  var length = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(body, null).width) * 0.16; // based on hit and trial

  number11.style.height = length + 'px';
  number11.style.width = length + 'px';
}

window.onresize = changeSize;
changeSize();
```

I had used [`window.getComputedStyle(Element, null).property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to retrieve width of body.

[**Here is a Pen**](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/BqmLyw?editors=0100) that will display the responsiveness.